# When Logged Out how to change the link of my account menu Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can someone suggest me if someone logged out from WordPress Woocommerce then click on my account how to change the link?

I want instead of going to the login register page to the other page but only when the user logged out if user login it is fine

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below code will work :

```
function iconic_account_menu_items( $items ) {
     if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $items['information'] = __( 'your_page_name', 'page' );
     }
        return $items;

    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'iconic_account_menu_items', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: I want to redirect to this page /sing-in/  can you tell me how would be the code ? its not working ..............